# How do you monitor kubernetes nodes deployed using kops?

Tags: kubernetes, kops

We have some Kubernetes clusters that have been deployed using [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) in AWS.

We really like using the upstream/official images.

We have been wondering whether or not there was a good way to monitor the systems without installing software directly on the hosts?  Are there docker containers that can extract the information from the host?  I think that we are likely concerned with:

- Disk space (this seems to be passed through to docker via `df`
- Host CPU utilization
- Host memory utilization

Is this host/node level information already available through heapster?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a question about kops, but a question about operating Kubernetes.  kops stops at the point of having a functional k8s cluster.  You have networking, DNS, and nodes have joined the cluster.  From there your world is your oyster.

There are many different options for monitoring with k8s.  If you are a small team I usually recommend offloading monitoring and logging to a provider.

If you are a larger team or have more specific needs then you can look at such options as Prometheus and others.  Poke around in the https://github.com/kubernetes/charts repository, as I know there is a Prometheus chart there.

As with any deployment of any form of infrastructure you are going to need Logging, Monitoring, and Metrics.  Also, do not forget to monitor the monitoring ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am using https://prometheus.io/, it goes naturally with kubernetes.

Kubernetes api already exposes a bunch of metrics in prometheus format,
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx also exposes prometheus metrics (enable-vts-status: "true"), and you can also install https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter as a daemonset to monitor CPU, disk, etc...

I install one prometheus inside the cluster to monitor internal metrics and one outside the cluster to monitor LBs and URLs.
Both send alerts to the same https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager that MUST be outside the cluster.

It took me about a week to configure everything properly.
It was worth it.